# Handle special character in Key in Jq query

Tags: jq

I have this jq query where i am adding path as a key so later i can get the value for the path but this is giving the error

```
gojq.Parse(".data[]|{.id: .id, name: .name, disk_capacity: .disks[].capacityGB,  disk_name: .disks[]|.name,}")
```

Error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x1119d71]
```

Comment: Are you using `gojq` Go pkg? or the gojq command line binary?

Comment: Remove the comma before the closing brace `}`.

Comment: i am using gojq. and wanted to add the path as a key. here the issue looks like key has a special character that need to be escaped which i don't know

Comment: in addation to this do we have any function which can do this automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to solve this like below

```
gojq.Parse(`.data[]|{".id": .id, ".name": .name, ".disks[].capacityGB": .disks[].capacityGB,  ".disks[]|.name": .disks[]|.name,}`)
```